# How to create a query with a parameter comparison condition with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want create query which will select banners by category ReqName field and if there are more than one banners in the category, then display a banner with a large Price field.

I use JPA query. I managed create query, which select banners by category ReqName and displays text. Can I use JPA without resorting to Specification to make such a request described above?

Repository:

```
List<Banner> findByCategoryReqName(String req_name);
```

Test:

```
Iterable<Banner> test = bannerRepository.findByCategoryReqName("First");
test.forEach(t-> System.out.println(t.getText()));
```

Output:

```
SecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecond
FirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirst
```

Comment: How is your model defined? And could you clarify your question? I don't understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following jpa query:

```java
@Query("select b from Banner b where b.category.reqName = :reqName and b.price >= all (select ban.price from Banner ban where ban.category.reqName = :reqName) ")
List<Banner> findByCategoryReqName(@Param("reqName") String req_name);
```

See [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-relational-comparisons) of hibernate documentation.

The query does not look very efficient, but it looks like to be more efficient you should write a native sql query.

As it's stated in jpa 2.2 specification:

> Subqueries may be used in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause.
> Subqueries are restricted to the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses in this release. Support for subqueries in the `FROM` clause will be considered in a later release of this specification.